# Background Image not showing in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, background, background-image

I've checked lots of other posts on this subject but I seem to already be complying with all the responses.

I am designing a website that works perfectly in all browsers except the dreaded IE. In all other browsers my background image works perfectly, but when I check in IE, nothing.

Here is my code CSS code, can anyone suggest what I may have missed?

```
#central_section {
width: 1024px;
height: 600px;
background-image: url('../img/Mountains.png');
background-color: #F8F8F8;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
font-family: Pacifico, Antonio, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
}
```

Comment: Which version(s) of IE?

Comment: 11 but I haven't tried it on any other version yet

Comment: Seems fine. http://liveweave.com/fpCxPO IE 11.0.9600 on Win7/64.

Comment: Well I'm flummoxed then as I've just checked and still doesn't work when I try it.

Comment: I don't know if it helps or not but I've also noticed that it isn't showing the background color either.

Comment: Just so we're looking at the same stuff, can you put the offending code in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)? Or provide a link to your site, but a fiddle is much preferred.

Comment: Anyway, what you can try is clear the cache, or load the image directly into the browser. Does that work?

Comment: I'd already tried clearing the cache to no avail... How do I add images to JSFiddle? I've never used it before.

Comment: ...and another thing I've noticed. IE is completely ignoring the height I've set

Comment: Ehmmmm.. Is IE ignoring all the styles? Also the font family and size?